# Rails Simple Form CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a rails 4 app which I am using with Simple Form and Bootstrap.

I have a submit button which I am trying to style with my own CSS.

I have a css file called scopes.css.scss which is part of a tree in the application.css.scss (so it is getting picked up) and I have appended !important to all css attributes.

The styling isn't applying to my button. My code is below. Does anyone know how to apply styling to Simple Form?

The form element is:

```
  <%= f.button :submit, "Get Started", :input_html =>{:class => "create-gs"} %>
```

The CSS is:

```
.create-gs {
  background-color:#7491A3 !important;
     display:inline-block !important;
     color:white !important;
     font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif !important;
     font-size:20px;
     font-weight:bold !important;
     text-decoration:none !important;
 }
 .create-gs:hover {
     background-color:#7491A5 !important;
 }
 .create-gs:active {
     position:relative!important;
     top:1px !important;
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
<%= f.submit "Get Started", :class => "create-gs" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<%= f.button :submit, "Get Started", class: "create-gs" %>`  and make sure that your  button picks up `.create-gs{}` class.